# Jupyterでcmd + / キーと逆インデントができなくなりました

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

**実現したいこと**
Jupyter(Notebook, Lab共に)で

- cmd + / キーができるように戻したい
- 逆インデントができるように戻したい
- インデントした際にインデントした分だけ謎の矢印が出るので消去したい

**発生している問題**
タイトルと上記の通りですが，Jupyterでcmd + / キーと逆インデントができなくなりました．さらに，インデントした際に出る謎の矢印も消したいです．

お恥ずかしいことに，もしかすると自分自身で何か操作をして設定を変更してしまったのかもしれません．マウス操作で設定を開き何かボタンを押したり消去したりなどそういったことはしていないため，なぜこうなったのかが全くわかりません．

**試したこと**

- cmd と / どちらとも片方のみ，または他のキーと組み合わせて使った際（cmd+cやshift+/など）は問題なく動きます．
- Jupyterでのみこれが発生します，その他のエディタ（VScode，Google colab）では問題なく動きます．

**謎の矢印の例**
[image: 謎の矢印の例]

**備考**
3つのうち，どれかだけでも解決策がわかる方いらっしゃいましたら教えていただきたいです．初めてこのサイトを利用するため，質問の情報としてどの程度必要なのかがわかりません．もし気になる点などございましたらご指摘いただけますと幸いです．宜しくお願い致します．

Comment: settingsの key mapはどのようになってますか？ / 謎の矢印のように見えるのはタブ文字でしょう。インデント方法を変更すると良いでしょう (SPC 4つとか)

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/h9l2bxpok5vquz) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)